# What is the preferred way to get Angular JS on a windows machine?

Tags: angularjs

What is the preferred way to get Angular JS on a windows machine?

The online documentation says to use Git or Git Hub Desktop.  A peer tells me to use Visual Studio and the NuGet Package Manager Console.

Comment: You want to get what? The source code?

Comment: "preferred" is opinion-based. Usually your libraries should be managed by nuget, npm, bower etc. The trend now for most users is to use `npm` with client-side libraries